# Shared objects access variable of static library, variable is different each other

Tags: c, static-libraries

I create libxa.a has a variable(int p) and a function(void increase()) increasing p.
Shared objects(libxb.so and libxc.so) each have function(void b() and c()) calling void increase().
main call void b() and void c().

```
main --+-- libxb.so --+-- libxa.a  
       |              |
       +-- libxc.so --+
```

Calling void b() works as well as I thought.
But void c() is not. I thought that 14 and 15 is printed, but 12 and 13 is printed like void b().

I think that the variable(int p) accessed from shared object is different each other.
How can I fix it?

followings is source.

```
// a.h
void increase();

// a.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "a.h"

int p = 11;

void increase()
{
    p++;
    printf("===[%i]===\n", p);
}

// b.h
void b(void);

// b.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "b.h"
#include "a.h"

void b(void)
{
    increase();
}

// c.h
void c(void);

// c.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "c.h"
#include "a.h"

void c(void)
{
    increase();
}

// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include "b.h"
#include "c.h"

int main()
{
    void(*b)(void);
    void* lb = dlopen("./libxb.so", RTLD_NOW);
    b = (void(*)(void))dlsym(lb, "b");
    void(*c)(void);
    void* lc = dlopen("./libxc.so", RTLD_NOW);
    c = (void(*)(void))dlsym(lc, "c");

    b();  // ===[12]===
    b();  // ===[13]===
    c();  // NOT ===[14]=== BUT ===[12]===
    c();  // NOT ===[15]=== BUT ===[13]===
}

// CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
project ("Test")

add_library(xa STATIC a.c)
set_property(TARGET xa PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE TRUE)
add_library(xb SHARED b.c)
add_library(xc SHARED c.c)

target_link_libraries(xb xa)
target_link_libraries(xc xa)

add_executable(xm main.c)
target_link_libraries(xm dl)
```

Thank you for your attention in advance.

Comment: Try calling `b` and `c` directly from `main` and linking the main program with libxb and libxc.

Comment: maybe `p` must be declared as extern in all other modules

Comment: In your program, you will have three instances of `libx.a`: one linked into the main executable, one linked into `libxb.so` and one linked into `libxb.so`. Depending the dlopen-options, some of them might hide others. The solution is turning libxa.a into shared object libxa.so

Comment: @arfneto Thank you your attention. I added "extern in p;" to a.h. But it does not work as I thought.

Comment: @dbush Thank you your attention. Every time creating so file, rebuilding main is inconvinient, as I would like to use so file in plugin.

Comment: @ZsigmondLőrinczy Thank you for your attention. It works as well as I thought.

Comment: You don't need to rebuild the main program if one of the shared libraries changes, not unless you change how the function is called.

Comment: `extern int p;` would be in the other headers, not in `a` where it is in fact declared.